# Unit testing Error part of Angular Service which Returns Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, observable

I am trying to test a very simple piece of code:

**component.ts**

```
createSet(dataSetPayload: SetPayload): void {
    this.setsService.addSet(dataSetPayload).subscribe(
      (set: Set) => {
        this.hideCreateSetForm();
        this.setsDomainModel.updateSets(Set);
      },
      (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        this.createSetError = error;
      }
    );
  }
```

What I need to cover in my coverage is the error part of the function which has **this.createSetError = error;** line.

**service.ts**

```
addSet(setPayload: SetPayload): Observable<Set> {
    return this.httpService
      .post(`${API_PATHS.SETS.ADD_SET}`, setPayload)
      .pipe(
        map((set: Set) => {
          return set;
        })
      );
  }
```

I am out of ideas to mock the **addSet** functions using **jest.spyOn** method so that it directly enters the error block of the subscription. Is there anything I can try?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried using `throwError` from rxjs? If the mock `addSet` returns `throwError`, it should go directly to the error section of the subscribe.

Comment: Tried that, didnt work.

Comment: what your test look like?